# .env variable not a string, when trying to `yarn build` my Firebase project?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, yarnpkg, nuxt.js

I am trying to test my project on a production build, but every time I build my project with `yarn build` and then start it with `yarn start`, Firebase keeps giving me this error:

```
projectId must be a string in FirebaseApp.options
```

The ProjectId is stored inside my `.env` file and when I console log it, it comes out fine.

Comment: Did it work in the dev mode?
Did you try `.env.production` file?

Comment: Yes, it works when i run `yarn dev`, i have not tried the `.env.production`. Can you explain a bit more about the `.env.production`?

Comment: You can define `.env.production` and `.env.development` which will work in corresponding environment

Comment: Sorry but im still new to this. Do i just make a file named `.env.production`? the same as the regular `.env` file?

Comment: Yeah, that right. You can read more at https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work. It is still throwing the same error as before.

Comment: Update your question with any code related to the problem please

Comment: I fixed the problem by adding `require('dotenv').config();` to my `nuxt.config` file. Thanks for you help tho!

Comment: I think you should write it as an answer - it can help other people who can run into similar issues

Comment: Vote on [this proposal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354583/disentangle-the-yarn) to ease the tag confusion.

Answer (score 0):

By doing some more research i found out none of my `.env` variables were working. I fixed this issue by adding this line of code to my `nuxt.config.js`: `require('dotenv').config();`